# How do I fix this Elastic Beanstalk error when deploying a Flask app: Python 3.7.0 was not found on your system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Flask app using the EB CLI following this official [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html). I receive the error 'Create environment operation is complete, but with errors'. Observing the environment logs, the server seems to be lacking the correct Python version.

Below are the EB environment details, my PipFile, the EB CLI output and the error in the deploy logs.

How can I fix this problem?

*Environment details:*

```
 Application name: server_eb
  Region: eu-west-2
  Deployed Version: XXX
  Environment ID: XXX
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2020-06-02 16:53:10.321000+00:00
```

*PipFile:*

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
flask = "~=1.1.1"
python-dotenv = "~=0.13.0"
psycopg2 = "~=2.8.5"
flask-sqlalchemy = "~=2.4.1"
flask-migrate = "~=2.5.3"
flask-dance = {extras = ["sqla"],version = "~=3.0.0"}
flask-login = "~=0.4.1"
blinker = "~=1.4"
flask-session = "==0.3.1"
redis = "==3.4.1"

[scripts]
migrate="flask db upgrade"
start="flask run --cert=cert.pem --key=key.pem"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7.0"
```

*CLI output:*

```
2020-06-02 16:54:55    ERROR   [Instance: XXX] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-06-02 16:54:55    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-06-02 16:55:57    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: ServiceError - Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

*Logs:*

```
2020/06/02 16:54:55.030996 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [SetUpPythonEnvironment]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install Gunicorn with error Command /bin/sh -c python3 -m pipenv install gunicorn --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Warning: the environment variable LANG is not set!
We recommend setting this in ~/.profile (or equivalent) for proper expected behavior.
Warning: Python 3.7.0 was not found on your systemâ€¦
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

Comment: EB uses `Python 3.7.6`, so maybe using that instead of 3.7.0 will help.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, that did the trick. Where is this documented?

Comment: I just checked on my EB instance what it the exact python version. If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference. Also the link to Python version on EB this is in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin that's useful

Comment: what is the PipFile? not the requirements file? Where do i locate and update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was that the EB uses `Python 3.7.6`, while the OP's dependencies required version 3.7.0.

The **solution** was to change the dependency to `Python 3.7.6`.

The **current python version running on EB** can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python):

> 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.1 running Python 3.7 - **Python 3.7.6**