# AWS EB: Passing private pypi credentials to environment in deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pipenv

I am working with a Django project deployed in Elastic Beanstalk. I want to add a dependency to the project via pipenv. This dependency includes sensitive credentials in the URL, passed via env variable. I am able to do this locally and on Github Actions, but when I add the variable to EB's environment properties, pipenv doesn't seem to be able to access it to install the package when I run `eb deploy`. I am able to retrieve the env variable when I ssh into an instance and use `get-config`. I've also tried exporting the password in a prebuild hook script, which has not worked.

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://user:${PRIVATE_PYPI_PASSWORD}@private-pypi.company.com"
verify_ssl = true
name = "Private_PYPI"
```

Here's the top of the trace for the error I'm getting:

```
2020/12/29 22:36:42.955636 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with Pipfile file with error Command /bin/sh -c python3 -m pipenv install --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:An error occurred while installing private-pypi-package! Will try again.
```

And here's the end of it

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 256, in handle_401
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     username, password, save = self._prompt_for_password(parsed.netloc)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 226, in _prompt_for_password
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     username = ask_input("User for {}: ".format(netloc))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 262, in ask_input
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     return input(message)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172429/6505847

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! My pipfile's python version dependency is working fine with eb; if I take out the private pypi package, the environment installs cleanly.